# Finite groups with no elements of order $p^2q$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group.  What can be said if $G$ has the following Property P: $G$ has no element of order $p^2q$ for *any* two distinct primes $p,q$?

> In particular, which finite simple groups satisfy Property P?

For instance, the alternating group $\text{Alt}_n$ has Property P if and only if $n\le 8$. The question for $\text{PSL}_2$ of finite fields seems not obvious.

As a side remark, a result of Malle, Moreto and Navarro states the following:

> Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. If $G$ does
>   not have any elements of order $pq$, then one of the following holds:
>
> 1. The Sylow $p$-subgroups or the Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G$ are abelian.
> 2. $G/O_{\{p,q\}′} (G)$ = $M$ and $\{p, q\} = \{5, 13\}$ or $\{7, 13\}$.

Here $M$ is the Monster sporadic group, and $O_{\{p,q\}′} (G)$ is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ that is divisible by neither $p$ nor $q$.

Comment: What do you want to know?

Comment: the question specified to finite simple groups seems interesting, even for $PSL_2$ of finite fields. But it strongly depends on whether $p$ and $q$ are supposed to be distinct.

Comment: For the record, I voted to close as "too broad".

Comment: yes of course p and q are distinct. I edited. Thanks.

Comment: I have groups that order of every elements does not divides by $p^2q$, $p\ne q$.

Comment: You consider two cases. Let $G$ be a simple or not simple.

Comment: @Mousavi: this is better but it is also asked to clarify other things. First you seem to mean "finite group" instead of "group". And also "What can be said" is too broad.

Comment: To follow Yves's comment: make your own conjecture, and test it.

Comment: "Most" finite simple groups will have an element of order 12, and it should not be too hard to use the classification to list exactly which simple groups do not. So the problem is approachable for simple groups. For general finite groups, I doubt whether you can say anything very interesting.

Comment: I have tried to improve the formulation of the question, though I don't know whether anything interesting can be said about groups having the described property.

Comment: I had a look. If $p\ge 5$ is prime then both $PSL_3(F_p)$ and $PSL_2(F_{p^2})$ have an element of order 12. There are some other cases I skip. Finally for odd prime $PSL_2(F_p)$ has orders precisely the divisors of $p$, $(p-1)/2$ and $(p+1)/2$. So for infinitely many $p$ this has a element of order $4q$ for some prime $p$, but probably (conjecturally?) for infinitely many $p$ (with positive density), both $(p-1)/2$ and $(p+1)/2$ are square-free and thus $PSL_2(F_p)$ has no element of the required order.

Comment: I think this is a good question, except that "for any" should be changed to "for some". It is related to a situation studied by Malle, Moreto and Navarro. The connection to their paper is enough to make it worth while.

Comment: I have edited this question heavily to give a suggestion of the sort of result that the OP might be looking for. I hope that it is now clear enough to be re-opened.

Comment: @Nick: I see another ambiguity: I understood the question as "what can be said of $G$ having no element of order $p^2q$ for any distinct primes $p,q$. You seem to understand it as "given $p,q$ distinct primes, what can be said of $G$ having no element of order $p^2q$. I don't have any guess on the correct interpretation but these are drastically different. Mousavi, could you clarify please.

Comment: I asked exactly: "What can be said about the structure of a finite group which does not have an element of order $p ^2 q$  for any distinct primes p  and q ?" ($p,q\in \pi(G)$). But it is also intresting that given $p,q$. Thank you. Gill and cormulier.

Comment: @Yves, I spent some time thinking about that too. I opted to state the weakest assumption - since that allows for all possibilities. It also naturally extends the MMN result that I stated in the question.

Comment: So, well, in a sense, the question as currently edited by Nick Gill is well-asked but very far from the original question. So I'll edit again; I suggest the question for $(p,q)$ fixed to be asked separately if you'd like to maintain it.

Comment: Well, @NickGill and Yves are certainly making stone soup here...

Comment: I was actually rather tempted to just remove the reference to Malle-Moreto-Navarro, which is of little relevance to the question (since the question is subtle in cases such as $PSL_2$ for which this MMN result is trivial). Anyway, the question should be reopened, or closed for good, otherwise it's just noise.

Comment: Good work Yves. Yes, surely it's OK for it to be re-opened now? And, Yemon, nice reference. After consulting wikipedia I now know what stone soup is.

Comment: @NickGill What is the MMN result?

Comment: @Felix: the MMN result is in the question (Malle Moreto Navarro).

Answer (score 4):

It seems hard to give a complete answer to this, but at the very least one should be able to specify what the composition factors of $G$ might be. To do this it is enough to classify which simple groups $G$ have property $P$, in which case:

- if $G$ is alternating, then @Yves asserted that $n\leq 8$;
- if $G$ is sporadic, then we can consult the ATLAS and do each group one by one. For instance, of the Mathieu groups, $M_{11}, M_{12}, M_{22}$ and $M_{23}$ have property P, but $M_{24}$ does not;
- suppose next that $G$ is a quasisimple group of type $A_4$ over a field of characteristic $p$, i.e. is isomorphic to a quasisimple cover of $PSL_5(p^a)$, and suppose that $p^a>3$. Since $p^a>3$, there is a non-trivial element of a split torus of order $q$, that has a centralizer equal to a quasisimple cover of $PSL_4(p^a)$. Since the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $PSL_4(p^a)$ has exponent $>p$ and we obtain an element of order $p^2q$. We can consult the ATLAS to see that $PSL_5(2)$ contains an element of order 12. Thus any quasisimple group of type $A_4$ contains an element of order $p^2q$ for some primes $p$ and $q$, i.e. it does not satisfy property P.
- Now any simple group of Lie type which contains a subgroup of type $A_4$ will also fail to satisfy P. This includes, in particular, $E_6, {^2E_6}, E_7, E_8$ plus all of the classical groups of dimension at least 10.
- We've dealt with all groups of Lie type or large rank ($\geq 5$), and we should be able to deal with `of medium rank' groups (say rank 3 or 4) with *ad hoc* methods. For instance the ATLAS tells us that the Tits group ${^2F_4}(2)'$ contains an element of order $12$ and so we can immediately rule out $G={^2F_4}(q)$ and $G=F_4(q)$ and that deals with all of the exceptional groups of (twisted) rank at least $3$.
- We are left with the situation when $G$ is a low rank group of Lie type (say rank 1 or 2). In this case (as the comments indicate) the question is subtle and somewhat number-theoretic. For instance for $PSL_2(q)$ and for ${^2B_2}(q)$ one needs to determine when the order of a maximal torus of $G$ is divisible by $p^2q$ for some primes $p$ and $q$.